# Can I pass the EASA ATPL exams by studying FAA materials?

Tags: faa-regulations, easa-regulations, pilot-certification, international

If I have the theoretical knowledge required for an FAA ATP, could I use that knowledge to pass the EASA ATPL exams?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "pass" the exam? In some languages that means to take or sit the exam; in others it means to successfully complete the exam. I'm not sure if you're asking if a) knowing the FAA material is good enough to answer the EASA questions, or b) you're allowed to sit an EASA exam after doing an FAA study course. My edit assumes (a) but I might be wrong.

Comment: Someone will surely come in with an answer, but I recall that you cannot sit the EASA exams without first completing an EASA approved course. I doubt the syllabuses are all dramatically different but I think EASA goes into a lot more detail than the FAA.

Comment: @Pondlife What variety of English uses the word "pass"  to mean "take or sit an exam (without necessarily obtaining a favorable grade or mark)"? I don't think I've ever heard that usage.

Comment: @TannerSwett Non-English speakers often confuse "taking" and "passing" exams and I thought it was worth clarifying here; the question is very short so there's no context to confirm the meaning. I'm not saying that Ucha is using it incorrectly, but it's a very common source of confusion.

Answer (score 6):

If you are asking about knowledge - you can use some points, but generally FAA ATP knowledge is insufficient. EASA has 14 subjects, and requires much stronger theoretical background. Just go through the EASA learning objectives and you will see it.

Moreover, there are some differences in Air Law (EASA exam pretends to be ICAO-based only, but in fact it asks about European regulations as well), IFR and VFR communications, and even units of measurement (for example, EASA has some questions where you pick altitudes in metres, not in feet).

And, finally, you cannot even sit the exams without taking a theoretical course in some EASA-approved flight school. That means that you usually need a course completion certificate before going to CAA. There is another way if you have 1500 hours under your belt, but that is a completely different story, and in that case sometimes you don't need to sit the exams at all.

Comment: There are lot of online question banks which helps you clear atpl. Just work hard. https://www.hashtrek.com/groups/atpl-question-bank#latest