# What are the differences between FAA and EASA PPL(A) written exams?

Tags: faa, ppl, easa

Would studying for FAA PPL(A) written exam prepare you just as well for the EASA PPL(A) written exam, or is the knowledge base requirements (and study contents) significantly different in each?

I've found that PPL(A) FAA exam requires these below:
https://pilotinstitute.com/faa-private-pilot-written-checklist/

```
Regulations 
Accident Reporting
Performance Charts  
Radio Communications    
Weather
Safe and Efficient Operations   
Density Altitude Performance    
Weight and Balance  
Aerodynamics, Powerplants, and Aircraft Systems 
Stalls and Spins    
Aeronautical Decision-Making (ADM)  
Preflight actions
```

and PPL(A) EASA, apparently requires these:
https://www.modularpilot.co.uk/how-to-pass-your-ppl-private-pilot-licence-theory-exams/814

```
Theory / Fact Learning Exams

Air Law
Operational Performance
Human Performance and Limitations
Aircraft General Knowledge
Principles of Flight
Communications

Practical / Fact Learning Exams

Meteorology
Navigation
Flight Performance & Planning
```

Just doing a quick glance comparison, the requirements seem to vary.
I was considering an online resource that has good review (Sporty's ground school) but I want to know if this resource would even be compatible for preparing for the EASA PPL(A) exam (since I live in Europe).

Thanks

Comment: Related (ATPL): [Can I pass the EASA ATPL exams by studying FAA materials?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/37605/14897)

Comment: In Europe you should have access to relatively affordable training through an aeroclub, at least from my experience in France and Germany. Why not get a book or other EASA materials and take classes at your club?

Comment: Thanks for the info @Raketenolli, I am a newbie at this and had no idea there was that option. I will look for aeroclubs here in Spain. My ideal scenario would be to study on my own and take the exam when I'm ready, but apparently, at least from what I've read, in Spain, a school needs to 'recommend-approve' me as 'ready to take the exam' so I can then register to take it exam. I'll contact AESA here in Spain to see if there are workarounds for that. Thanks again

Comment: This is a great question. Another way to ask it is whether someone who has recently studied for and passed one of them can "top off" their knowledge with a brief evening review of major FAA/EASA differences and expect to pass the other or whether they would have to go back and learn entirely different concepts, techniques, etc.

Comment: It seems a good starting point to finding a suitable club is https://realaeroclubdeespaña.org/aeroclubs-2/ From my own personal experience, doing theory (studying) and practical training in parallel works best, just because you can more easily relate the two and applying what you learn helps you retain it.